# What test to use to find which proportion is highest in multiple groups of different sample sizes?

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion

I have 4 samples of different sizes. I have used chi-square test to find whether the male-female proportions are same in these samples and it came out statistically significantly different (p < 0.01). From the percentage value of male-females proportion in the samples, I can see that `% of males` are higher in `Sample A` than in other groups. Is there any test to make the statement `Males are higher in Sample A compared to other groups (p-value ???)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the significant chi-squared test on the four groups, you may want to do *ad hoc* tests
comparing Group A with other groups. Because you did not show your actual data, I will show how to do this for fictitious data, which may be
somewhat similar to yours.

---

Suppose you have a table of numbers of sales as follows:

```
     A    B    C    D
    ------------------  
 M  201  145  143  130
 F  170  152  148  211
```

In R:

```
m = c(201, 145, 143, 130)
f = c(170, 152, 148, 211)
TBL = rbind(m, f);  TBL

TBL
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
m  201  145  143  130
f  170  152  148  211
```

In R, a chi-squared test of homogeneity rejects
the null hypothesis that sales
of gender are homogeneous across groups at significance level $0.1%$ with P-value
$0.0003 < 0.001 = 0.1\%.$ The Yates continuity
correction is declined (parameter 'cor=F') on
account of reasonably large counts.

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 19.168, df = 3, p-value = 0.0002523
```

The chi-squared test compares the observed counts
in `TBL` with counts (based on marginal totals) that
would be expected under the null hypothesis of homogeneity. The Pearson residuals can show
where disagreement of observed and expected counts
is greatest; look especially for residuals with
largest absolute values. Here it seems that the
greatest contribution to the relatively large chi-squared statistic comes from groups A and D.

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)$resi
       [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
m  1.831823  0.3012389  0.377127 -2.540219
f -1.746446 -0.2871989 -0.359550  2.421826
```

You can do an *ad hoc* test to compare these
two groups by selecting only columns 1 and 4
of `TBL`. In order to avoid 'false discovery' from
repeated analyses on the same data, *ad hoc* tests
should be conducted at a smaller significance level
than the main chi-squared test. Here it is clear
that Groups A and D differ. Specifically, numbers of sales
by males are larger in A and sales by females are
larger in D.

```
chisq.test(TBL[,c(1,4)], cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL[, c(1, 4)]
X-squared = 18.41, df = 1, p-value = 1.781e-05
```

+Note:_ Another, essentially equivalent, version of the
chi-squared test in R is 'prop.test' as follows:
It shows proportions of sales by makes in each group.
The proportions $0.542$ and $0.381$ were shown
to be significantly different by the *ad hoc* chi-squared test above.

```
t = m+f
prop.test(m, t, cor=F)

        4-sample test for 
        equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  m out of t
X-squared = 19.168, df = 3, p-value = 0.0002523
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
    prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4 
 0.5417790 0.4882155 0.4914089 0.3812317
```